# Geting data from table with Scrapy, different row order per page

Tags: python, scrapy

So I have scrapy working really well. It's grabbing data out of a page, but the problem I'm running into is that sometimes the page's table order is different. For example, the first page it gets to:

```
Row name        Data
Name 1          data 1
Name 2          data 2
```

The next page it crawls to might have the order completely different. Where `Name 1` was the first row, any other page it might be the 3rd, or 4th etc. The row names are always the same. I was thinking of doing this possibly 1 of 2 different ways, I'm not sure which will work or which is better.

First option, use some `if` statements to find the row I need, and then grab the following column. This seems a little messy but could work.

Second option, grab all the data in the table regardless of order and put it in a `dict`. This way, I can grab the data I need based on row name. This seems like the cleanest approach.

Is there a 3rd option or a better way of doing either?

Here's my code in case it's helpful.

```
class pageSpider(Spider):
    name = "pageSpider"
    allowed_domains = ["domain.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://domain.com/stuffs/results",
    ]
    visitedURLs = Set()

    def parse(self, response):
        products = Selector(response).xpath('//*[@class="itemCell"]')
        for product in products:
            item = PageScraper()
            item['url'] = product.xpath('div[2]/div/a/@href').extract()[0]
            urls = Set([product.xpath('div[2]/div/a/@href').extract()[0]])
            print urls
            for url in urls:
                if url not in self.visitedURLs:
                    request = Request(url, callback=self.productpage)
                    request.meta['item'] = item
                    yield request

    def productpage(self, response):
        specs = Selector(response).xpath('//*[@id="Specs"]')
        item = response.meta['item']
        for spec in specs:
            item['make'] = spec.xpath('fieldset[1]/dl[1]/dd/text()').extract()[0].encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
            item['model'] = spec.xpath('fieldset[1]/dl[4]/dd/text()').extract()[0].encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
            item['price'] = spec.xpath('fieldset[2]/dl/dd/text()').extract()[0].encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
        yield item
```

The xpaths in `productpage` can contain data that doesn't correspond to what I need, because the order changed.

Edit:
I'm trying the `dict` approach and I think this is the best option.

```
def productpage(self, response):
    specs = Selector(response).xpath('//*[@id="Specs"]/fieldset')
    itemdict = {}
    for i in specs:
        test = i.xpath('dl')
        for t in test:
            itemdict[t.xpath('dt/text()').extract()[0]] = t.xpath('dd/text()').extract()[0]
        item = response.meta['item']
    item['make'] = itemdict['Brand']
    yield item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like the best and cleanest approach (using `dict`)

```
def productpage(self, response):
    specs = Selector(response).xpath('//*[@id="Specs"]/fieldset')
    itemdict = {}
    for i in specs:
        test = i.xpath('dl')
        for t in test:
            itemdict[t.xpath('dt/text()').extract()[0]] = t.xpath('dd/text()').extract()[0]
        item = response.meta['item']
    item['make'] = itemdict['Brand']
    yield item
```